# List fonts available to the app without native code

Tags: react-native

Is is possible to list all the fonts available to the app, without writing any sort of native code like the one mentioned on this blog?

https://medium.com/@dabit3/adding-custom-fonts-to-react-native-b266b41bff7f#.9slq5cpi6

I am aware that it is possible to add fonts to your project using rnpm or react-native link.

It would be really nice if we could get all the useable font list from command line as well.

Comment: [Adding Custom Fonts to A React Native Application for IOS](https://medium.com/@dabit3/adding-custom-fonts-to-react-native-b266b41bff7f#.3lowkx2v0)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but what I wanted was a way to list the fonts from JS code or command line, and not through native code @stereodenis

Comment: did you find the solution?